# Anchroing Fab Button

Tags: android, android-layout, anchor, floating-action-button

How do i anchor fab at the red marked position in image attached below. Any help is appreciated. Also please visit this git hub link to suggest change.
[Github link](https://github.com/atulsj/reader-xyz/blob/master/XYZReader/src/main/res/layout-sw600dp-land/fragment_article_detail.xml)

[image: Image for reference]

Comment: share your layout code with question

Comment: try using margin property

Comment: for code i have provided git hub link please refer from there.

Comment: @Asjadaun remove **`android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"`** from FAB

Comment: @chandani c shekhat ,@Nilu thanks both of your suggestions helped.

Comment: @Asjadaun happy to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**As per my above comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48047333/anchroing-fab-button/48047403#comment83066354_48047333)

Just remove `android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"` from **FloatingActionButton**

like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/share_fab"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_height"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:rippleColor="@color/secondaryDarkColor"
                android:contentDescription="@string/action_share"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_share"
                app:borderWidth="0dp"
                app:elevation="@dimen/fab_elevation"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/meta_bar"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="right|bottom" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/share_fab"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_height"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:rippleColor="@color/secondaryDarkColor"
            android:contentDescription="@string/action_share"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_share"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="700dp"
            app:elevation="@dimen/fab_elevation"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/meta_bar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
```

I have done it like this.